# Modify the markup for markers on the SVG map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js, geojson

I'm new to react and d3 and I'm trying to implement a simple SVG map with D3 v6.2 and ReactJS, which will indicate the location of some cities. Each city is being indicated by circles as shown below:

[image]

I need to change this marking to put a pin with the name of the city (using a div if possible) as shown in this image:

[image]

But the point's symbol shape is determined by D3-path itself and I can't find anything that can change or replace with another markup.

Note: I tried to put a `div` within the `path` tags of the points, but I realized that they were not rendered and the only change I was able to make was to change the radius of the mark with `pointRadius ()` but I don't want to do that.

Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { select, geoPath, geoMercator } from "d3";
import useResizeObserver from 'use-resize-observer';

import drawMap from './mapa.json';
import dataMap from './city.json';

const svgRef = useRef(null);
const wrapperRef = useRef(null);

const { widthRef, heightRef } = useResizeObserver({ wrapperRef });

function map(){

    useEffect(() => {

        const svg = select(svgRef.current);
        const { width, height } = wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
       
        const projection = geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], selectedEstados || drawMap);
        
        let pathGenerator = geoPath().projection(projection).pointRadius(4);
        console.log("path: " + pathGenerator)
        
         svg.selectAll(".estado")
            .data(drawMap.features)
            .join("path")
            .attr("class", "estado")
            .attr("d", features => pathGenerator(features));

         svg.selectAll(".city")
            .data(dataMap.features)
            .join("path")
            .attr("class", "city")
            .attr("d", features => pathGenerator(features))
                        
}, [drawMap, wrapperRef, widthRef, heightRef])

return(
    <div className='map' ref={wrapperRef}>
        <svg ref={svgRef}></svg>
    </div>
)
}
```

**city.json**

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "city",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "municipio": "sapé"
                
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -41.821476100786512,
                    -8.282815195947387
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "municipio": "muito distante"
                
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -41.065329661162544,
                    -7.183034162673664
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**mapa.json**

[map geojson here](https://github.com/26messias26/geo/blob/main/README.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of options, the simplest is likely just using SVG paths to draw your pin shapes.

*The path generator will not help us here. Instead we'll use the projection directly, `projection([longitude,latitude])` will return `[x,y]` in pixels. This projected x,y coordinate will let us anchor our marker to the correct location on the map. The geojson you are using conveniently has a property containing the longitude and latitude. Below I just use a simple non-geojson array for simplicity.*

Below I plot each city as a `g` element with an appropriate translate, which allows me to then place text, path, and circle elements relative to the city:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 400);
var projection = d3.geoMercator();

var cityData = [{name:"Vancouver",longlat:[-123,49]},{name:"Anchorage",longlat:[-150,61]}];

var cities = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(cityData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate("+projection(d.longlat)+")";
  })
  
// Two different paths for comparison:
cities.append("path")
  .attr("d", (d,i) => ["M0,0 Q0 -20 -40 -20 L-40 -40L40 -40L40 -20 Q 0 -20 0 0",
                       "M0,0 L-40 -20L-40 -40L40 -40L40 -20Z"][i] )
  .attr("fill","#ddd")
  .attr("stroke","black")
  .attr("stroke-width",1);

cities.append("text")
  .attr("dy", -25)
  .text( function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("text-anchor","middle");
  
// optional circle
cities.append("circle")
  .attr("r", (d,i) => [2,6][i])
  .attr("fill", (d,i) => ["black","white"][i])
  .attr("stroke-width",(d,i) => [0,1][i])
```

```css
circle { stroke:black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In this case, the paths are fixed width: it just happens the names fill the pins out relatively well. You could determine the appropriate width for the pin and use that to create the path.

If you really want a div, you'll need to use an SVG foreignObject element. The reason you didn't see any div rendered is SVG doesn't have a div element in its namespace, HTML and SVG elements are not interchangable. A foreignObject let's us place HTML objects within an SVG. *Note: IE does not support ForeignObjects*.

Here's a quick mockup with a div in a foreignObject:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 400);
var projection = d3.geoMercator();

var cityData = [{name:"Vancouver",longlat:[-123,49]},{name:"Anchorage",longlat:[-150,61]}];

var cities = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(cityData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate("+projection(d.longlat)+")";
  })
  
var div = cities.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", -25)
  .attr("y", -35)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .append("xhtml:div")
  .attr("class","box arrow-bottom")
  .text(d=>d.name);
  
cities.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("fill","orange");
```

```css
/* css from https://codeconvey.com/css-message-box-with-arrow/ */

.box {
  height: auto;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.box.arrow-bottom:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: -15px;
  border-top: 15px solid black;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

The above is just hand positioned, there would be better examples of css styling that provide a more precise point for positioning.

A third option would be to position divs over the map SVG using absolute coordinates, this requires accounting for the position of the SVG on the page. It also makes zooming/panning slightly more complicated.